# How to restore DataTemplate?

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I set a DataTemplate for my LongListSelector:

```
<ctl:LongListSelector Loaded="listbox_Loaded" Name="listbox" SelectionChanged="listbox_selectionChanged">
    <ctl:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Border Background="Gray" MouseLeftButtonDown="listbox_itemClicked">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"  TextWrapping="Wrap" Width="350"/>
            </Border>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ctl:LongListSelector.ItemTemplate>
</ctl:LongListSelector>
```

After some actions I changed a view of some items from code and now need to restore this DataTemplate, that described above. How to do this from code?

There are some handlers. The first one gets value from TextBlock, the second one turns the selected item to red. When I select another item I should return the previous to gray color. It seems like attempt to restore DataTemplate doesn't work.

```
    private void listbox_selectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var lb = (LongListSelector)sender;
        var lbi = lb.SelectedItem.ToString();
        lb.ItemTemplate = Resources["ItemTemplateLongListSelector"] as DataTemplate;
        var categoryCode = CategoryCodes.ElementAt(CategoryNames.IndexOf(lbi));
        addedItem.Category = categoryCode;
    }

    private void listbox_itemClicked(object sender, System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        var border = (Border)sender;
        var borderBrush = new SolidColorBrush();
        borderBrush.Color = Color.FromArgb(255, 255, 0, 0);
        border.Background = borderBrush;
    }
```

Thank You!

Answer (score 1):

You can make a **Resource**:

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="ItemTemplateLongListSelector">
        <Border Background="Gray"
                MouseLeftButtonDown="listbox_itemClicked">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}"
                       TextWrapping="Wrap"
                       Width="350" />
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>

</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>
```

Bind **DataTemplate** to **ItemTemplate**:

```
        <phone:LongListSelector Loaded="listbox_Loaded"
                                Name="LongListSelector"
                                SelectionChanged="listbox_selectionChanged"
                                ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ItemTemplateLongListSelector}" />
```

To set standard DataTemplate in code behind you can do the following:

```
LongListSelector.ItemTemplate = Application.Current.Resources["ItemTemplateLongListSelector"] as DataTemplate;
```

OR

```
LongListSelector.ItemTemplate = Resources["ItemTemplateLongListSelector"] as DataTemplate;
```

I hope this will help!

Comment: When I reset standart DataTemplate this way it drops ItemsSource. It looks like all LongListSelector just disappeared.

Comment: @splash27 Added some extra information in the answer.

Comment: Thank you for help, but It doesn't restore the original view, nothing happens if I use the second way. Also added some extra info to my question.